# Free mapping components for Windows Store Apps?

Tags: c#, dictionary, gis, windows-store-apps

I have been using opensource GIS and mapping components in my .net projects, like sharpmap, mapnik, brutile. I mainly used them in winforms applications, now I am looking for these kind of components for windows store ('Metro' style desktop) apps. Bing map control is not an option for me because of licensing issues.

Until now, I have not found any windows store app targeted mapping free components. Do you know any of them? Do you know an opensource project in this topic I can participate?

Comment: Is it a mobile or desktop app? Microsoft offers a free license for commercial mobile apps. http://www.microsoft.com/maps/

Comment: It is not free, it is only free under a lot of restrictions. "Currently, users can get 500,000 transactions for free on their public or non-restricted applications. Also, public-facing Not for Profit, Education and Broadcast applications fall under this key type for free use."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a very promising one:
http://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com